# confusing on pointer and array

Tags: c

We have

```
 int a[5]={10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

I would like to know how does the following two code segment do?

```
 int *ptr = (int *)(&a+1);
 int *t = (int *)(&a -1);
```

If we have

```
 printf("%d  %d  %d \n", *(a+1), *(ptr-1), *(t+1));
```

What should be the result?

Comment: What did your program say when you tried it?

Comment: This was a test question and was not assumed to answer by running on a computer.

Comment: @user297850, sure, but why not run it on a computer now so that you can understand it?

Comment: @user Nobody answered the question straight, but the result will be `10 50 ??`, where `??` is some value at `&a - 4*(sizeof(int))`. Read caf's answer, it's got the best explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the problems come from the use of `&a`, which is a pointer to "an array of five integers", so that pointer arithmetic (when you think in terms of addresses) gets "scaled" by `sizeof(a)` (which might e.g. be 20 if `int` are 4 bytes and the compiler needs no padding for alignment purposes -- reasonable hypotheses, though far from certain of course.

So, after

```
int *ptr = (int *)(&a+1);
int *t = (int *)(&a -1);
```

`ptr` is a pointer to int at the memory address "sizeof(a) more than the address a", and `t` similarly for "sizeof(a) less than the address of a".  Therefore...:

```
 printf("%d  %d  %d \n", *(a+1), *(ptr-1), *(t+1));
```

> What should be the result?

Quite possibly a segmentation violation, otherwise `20` followed by two completely arbitrary integer values.  Since `ptr` and `t` are pointers to `int`, the address arithmetic scaling for their `-1` and `+1` does **not** compensate that done on `&a` (the scaling in terms of memory addresses is by `sizeof(int)`, not `sizeof(a)`!), so `ptr-1` and `t+1` are pointing to (alleged;-) `int`s that are respectively "a few `int`s after the end of `a`" and "a few `int`s before the start of `a`".

There's no way to know whether at those arbitrary addresses there is any memory which the process is allowed to address (whence the possibility for segmentation violatons), and, if any accessible memory *is* there, what its contents "seen as an `int`" might possibly be.

**Edit**: @caf points out that `ptr - 1` is *not* invalid -- it correctly points to the last element of `a`; so the output (unless there's a segmentation fault, which @NullUserException thinks is very unlikely but on this point we disagree;-) would start with `20 50` before the third, "arbitrary" junk.  Point is, per the C standard, it **is** valid to compute (though not to use) the pointer "just one past the end" of an array, **and** the sizeof an array **must** be exactly that array's length time the sizeof its elements (padding is allowed for an element's type, if needed, and if so it shows in the element's own sizeof, but not for the *array* as a whole).  Subtle, but important;-).

Comment: You're not quite right here.  `a`, the pointer to an array of integers, is not necessarily stored next to `*a`, the integers themselves.  The issue is not the scaling, but rather the level of referencing at which the arithmetic is done.  Take a closer look...

Comment: @user297850, Alex: The segfault/random memory dereference was exactly what I got, which you can see in the output mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: "sizeof(a) more than the address a" is not "(&a)+1", it's "(a+1)".  "&a+1" is "sizeof(int**) more than the address of a".

Comment: @Borealid, you're badly wrong _again_: `a+1` is the same thing as `&a[1]`, the address of the 1-th item of `a`, `sizeof(int)` more than the address of `a` (when looking at memory addresses).  `a` is not **a pointer** to an array of int, it **is** an array of int (decays to `int*` when used in expressions).  Cheez, man, printf all of these addresses with `&p` in a few lines of code and you'll see how my compiler agrees with me (and the C language, and its standard!-).

Comment: @Borealid: There are *no* `int **` values in the OPs code.  None at all.  Alex is correct - `&a + 1` creates a pointer that is 5 `int` s advanced in memory from the beginning of `a`.  `a` is **not** a pointer to an array of integers, `a` itself *is* the array of integers.

Comment: By the way, `*(ptr - 1)` is OK - it points at the last `int` in `a`.  `*(t + 1)` is garbage, though.

Comment: "There are no int ** values in the OPs code. None at all".  What is `&a`?  `a` is of type `int*`.  Which makes `&a`...  Did anyone bother to run test code other than me?

Comment: @Merlyn It's not a segfault if you've got an answer.

Comment: @Borealid: No, `a` is of type `int [5]`, and `&a` is of type `int (*)[5]`.  Compare `sizeof a` and `sizeof(int *)` to disabuse yourself of the notion that they are the same type.

Comment: @Alex: `a[1] = 20`, so shouldn't it be "20 followed by two completely arbitrary integer values" ?

Comment: @Alex Just a couple of minor corrections: (1) `*(a+1)` is 20, not 10 (2) `*(ptr-1)` is guaranteed to point at `a[4]`, (3) `*(t+1)` points at `a[-4]`, which is garbage, but very unlikely to segfault the program.

Comment: @Borealid, "Did anyone bother to run test code other than me? -- of course, see my `printf` example in a comment to your A.  Did _you_ run that `printf` yet? Just put it in a `main` right after the declaration of `a` as per the Q, then `return 0`, the rest doesn't matter.  What numbers do you see from your compiler?  How do you interpret those numbers given your utter misunderstanding of C's behavior wrt arrays and pointers?-)

Comment: @Lazer, yep, tx and +1 -- fixing now.

Comment: @cal, right, tx, +1 -- though we disagree about the "unlikely to segfault", that's not part of the C standard anyway;-).  I've edited the A to explain why I was wrong (computing, though not using, the address "one past the end" of an array _is_ guaranteed to be valid in C, _and_ `sizeof` of an array is not subject to compiler whim;-).

Comment: @Alex I say it's "unlikely to segfault" because they are equivalent to `a[5]` and `a[-5]`, or in case of `*(ptr-1)` and `*(t+1)`, `a[4]` and `a[-4]`

Comment: @NullUserException: I get what you are saying.  I saw that someone posted an answer to the effect of segfault, and replied in kind.  Either way it is still a broken program :)

Answer (score 6):

Since the type of `a` is *array-of-5-`int`s*, that means that the type of `&a` is *pointer-to-array-of-5-`int`s*.

When you add or subtract 1 from a pointer, you ask it to point to the next or previous object of that type in memory.  So `&a+1` is creating a pointer to the array-of-5-`int` immediately after `a` in memory (which doesn't exist), and `&a-1` is creating a pointer to the array-of-5-`int` immediately before `a` in memory (which also doesn't exist).  In memory, it looks like this (where each cell represents one `int`):

```
Address:    &a-1                      &a                      &a+1
Contents:  | ?  | ?  | ?  | ?  | ?  | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | ?  | ?  | ?  | ?  | ?  |
```

When `a` is used in the expression `*(a+1)`, it is converted to a pointer to its first element - so a pointer-to-`int` pointing at the `10` value.  Adding one to it then makes a pointer pointing at the next `int` - `a+1` points at the `20` value.  `*(a+1)` then fetches that value, so the first number printed is 20.

As `ptr` is also a pointer-to-`int`, that means that `ptr - 1` creates a pointer to the `int` immediately before `ptr` - in this case, it'll be pointing at the 50.  So the second number printed is 50.

Similarly, `t + 1` creates a pointer to the `int` immediately after `t` - in this case, it's the second `?` in the above diagram.  This is an uninitialised value - it could print anything at all, or even crash the program.

```
Address:    &a-1                      &a                       &a+1
            t    t+1                  a   a+1            ptr-1 ptr
Contents:  | ?  | ?  | ?  | ?  | ?  | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50  | ?  | ?  | ?  | ?  | ?  |
```

Comment: +1 I just want to add that the crisis could've been averted if those parentheses were removed (ie: `int *ptr = (int *) &a + 1`, which is the same as `int *ptr = ((int *) &a) +1`). Then it would print `20 10 10`

Comment: @Null, yes, but, more simply, `int* ptr = a + 1;` would be just fine -- `a`, being an array of `int`s, "decays" to "pointer to `int`" when used in an expression. No casts, nor complications, needed;-).

Comment: @NullUserException: A very nice observation, and one that shows clearly how the effect of the `+1` changes depending on the type of the pointer it's applied to.

Answer (score 0):

"What should be the result"?

Next time you want to know what a tiny code snippet like this should do, check this out:
http://ideone.com/4fCud

The result I got out of that was:

> 20  50  134520820

**Edit:**

When you run a program, see output like this, and find yourself asking, "where did *that* value come from?" you may have run into undefined behavior.

In this case the third value doesn't point to where you might think it would point.  It is reading uninitialized memory (most likely), memory owned by code that is in your process space, but outside your program (a library you loaded, or the C runtime), or memory that simply has nothing to do with this program (less likely, because of protected memory).

Comment: Uhh...  you do realize the third number is garbage based on whatever happened to be in memory at the time, right?

Comment: @darron: Yep, I know that.  The point of the post was to demonstrate that there were compilers online for simple questions like this, so the author need not ask it to begin with.  The better question for him to ask would have been "why isn't it outputting the values I expect?"

Comment: The problem is just that your answer doesn't mention the fact that the last number is garbage...  which is important here.  If someone wrote "20 50 134520820" as the answer to this on a test it'd be wrong.

Comment: @darron: I don't think that the test analogy applies here.  Discussions are provided in a QA format, but that simply lowers the barrier to entry.  I don't think Stack Overflow's purpose is *just* to provide answers, but to increase understanding.  I provided the answer the way I did because I didn't want to duplicate other people's efforts and information, and felt there was some value to the information I added.

Comment: @darron: However, at your persistence, I can add a note explaining the program's output :)

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at it piece by piece.

`&a` means the address of a.  So, it gets the address of the address of the integer 10.
`&a+1` is the next pointer over from that.  So it's the thing stored after the variable `a` in memory.  Bad idea.
`&a-1` is the thing stored before `a` in memory.  Again, bad idea.

`*(a+1)` is the thing at the location pointed to by a, plus one integer.  That would be `a[1]`, or 20.
`*(ptr-1)` is `a`, because `ptr` is `&a+1`, so `ptr-1` is `&a`.  It's the pointer value of `a`.  Printing it as `%d` is a mistake.  If you were to say `**(ptr-1)`, you'd get a more-meaningful `10` from the `printf`.
`*(t+1)` is also `a`, as per the above but with the pluses and minuses switched.

Comment: @Borealid, key defect in your answer: `ptr is &a+1, so ptr-1 is &a.` -- **NO**!!! You're ignoring the completely different scaling of those `+1` and `-1` (since `ptr` is a pointer to `int`, memory addresses in arithmetic on `ptr` are scaled by `sizeof(int)`, while memory addresses in arithmetic on `&a` are clearly scaled by `sizeof(a)` which must be several times more than `sizeof(int)`).

Comment: @Alex Martelli: Actually, if `ptr==&a+1`, then `ptr-1==&a`, on any standards-compliant C implementation on a 32-bit machine.  This is because all types being arithmetically manipulated are pointers, and on x86_32, sizeof(void*)==sizeof(int) and the size of all pointer types are the same.  So, no matter how many bold exclamation points you put, what I said was true.  Come back with test code if you're really sure of yourself.

Comment: @Borealid, you're simply, desperately wrong all the way -- have you **tried** some `printf("%p\n", (void*)(eachofthese))` for each of the pointer values `eachofthese` that you're mentioning, for goodness' sake?!

Comment: The key difference here is that `ptr` and `&a+1` have different types (`ptr` has type `int *`, and `&a+1` has type `int (*)[5]`) - so `ptr - 1` and `(&a+1)-1` do not calculate the same address.

Comment: @caf: Given `sizeof(int)==sizeof(int*)`, they do.  See my previous comment.

Comment: For example, ` printf("%p %p %p\n", (void*)&a, (void*)(&a+1), (void*)(((int*)&a)+1));` prints something like `0xbffff8bc 0xbffff8d0 0xbffff8c0` (exact numbers variable per platform, compiler and run, of course, but differences, not so much;-).  IOW, `&a+1` is 20 more (as a memory address) than `&a`, just as I said, while `((int*)&a)+1` is only 4 more than `&a`, ditto.  (gcc 4.0.1, MacOSX 10.5, Intel CPU).  What does *your* compiler show in this case, @Borealid?-)

Comment: @caf, right -- but @Borealid just won't listen.  Let's hope he does the `printf` I've suggested (and abundant variations thereof to his heart's contents;-) and thereafter repents (or will he go flat-earther, claim his compiler is buggy, etc?-)...

Comment: @Borealid: Those are the wrong types - the relevant sizes here are `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int [5])`, which clearly cannot be equal.