# Pointer to array not functioning as expected

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am expanding my knowledge of arcane C usage, especially with strange pointer types. I found a site with some examples and I've been trying them out. However, after playing with some of these examples, I found some strange behaviour relating to a pointer to an array. Here is the code:

```
int test = 45;
int *testp = &test;
int (*p)[1];
p = &testp;
printf("%d\n", **p);
```

This code outputs 2686744 (which I can make no sense of). My logic is as follows: an array is just a glorified pointer. I can make a pointer and call it an array of 1 if I like. So when I create the pointer testp, I expect it to function as an array of 1 int. Furthermore, I would expect the line `int (*p)[1];` to create an int** variable. However, there is something even worse about the whole thing. Here is a modified version of the above code:

```
int test[1] = {45};
int (*p)[1];
p = &test;
printf("%d\n", **p);
```

This outputs 45, as expected. So, my question is, what is the difference between these two snippets that causes the first to output garbage?

Thanks

Comment: `p` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: But shouldn't a pointer to an array function as a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: No, even though pointers and array may seem identical they are not.

Comment: No, the array-to-pointer decay (_lvalue conversion_) only happens to the outermost type. So, an array of elements of type "`T`" decays to a pointer to type `T` in most expressions, but an array of elements of type "array of `T`s" only decays to "pointer to array of `T`s", not to "pointer to pointer to `T`s". This is certainly a duplicate, I'm looking for a good one…

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437353/confusing-on-pointer-and-array) is at least a candidate, maybe answering your question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet is invalid and shall not be compiled

```
int test = 45;
int *testp = &test;
int (*p)[1];
p = &testp;
printf("%d\n", **p);
```

The type of expression `&testp` is `int **` while in the left side of the assignment there is an object of type `int (*)[1]`. There is no implicit conversion from one type to enother.

Nevertheless dereferencing p in the function call

```
printf("%d\n", **p);
```

that is *p will give array of type `int[1]` However the value stored in *p is the value of `testp`. Thus the only element of the array is the value stored in `testp` that  is the address of test (provided that sizeof( int * ) is equal to sizeof( int ).

So the output of the function is the address of `test`.

The second code snippet is valid. `*p` is an array with one element and `**P` gives the value of the first element of the aray.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. However, it's strange that gcc compiles the first snippet anyway...

Comment: @Mahkoe: gcc compiles virtually everything which is compilable somehow, by default, that is, it compiles some programmes, which are invalid according to the C standard. You've got a warning for it, I think.

Comment: @Mahkoe  i got error message error: assignment from incompatible pointer type when compiled the code with gcc.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I'm quite sure this is only a warning if not compiled with `-Werror` or `-pedantic-errors` or some other options…